# Geany text editor caret block

Tags: cursor, debian-jessie, geany, caret

I have Geany installed via apt-get on debian 8. I want to set the caret shape to be a block, but i can't find any `filetypes.common` in my `.config/geany/filedefs`. How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Tools > Configuration Files > filetypes.common` menu item.

It will automatically create `.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.common` file for you.

You can also copy it manually from `/usr/share/geany/filetypes.common`.

In order to set the caret shape you'll have to change `caret=caret` line to `caret=caret;;true`.